# Mat Tables : is there a way to set two headers one vertical and other horizontal?

Tags: angular-material, material-design, mat-table

I want to create a table with two headers (one vertical and the other one horizontal) using Material Table, like this one :

`header1 header2 header3 
header1    1        1      1
header2    2        2      2 
header3    3        3      3`

and I wonder if there is any direct manner to implement this ?! Basically what I found was implementations either for horizontal or vertical tables but not one with the two kinds of headers!

Comment: PROBABLY SOMEONE WILL NEED THIS : After long search , I opted for the easiest solution, I added name of horizontal titles to JSON response, and I applied same style of mat-header on cells of first column !